# Google Maps Distance Matrix Language specification for Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want a script to calculate distance between 2 points.

The problem is, i need the json output to be in my language (Greek).

If i use this url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&language=el&origins=TILEFOU%2019%20PATRA%20ACHAIA&destinations=leonidou%2019%20patra

the address returns to me in greek no matter how i enter it.

But if i use the js script i dont know how to set the language i prefer.

This is the script provided by Google:

```
function calculateDistance(origin, destination) {
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
  origins: [origin],
  destinations: [destination],
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
  avoidHighways: false,
  avoidTolls: false
}, callback);
```

}

But i cant find any param for language, is there any trick or id have to create a script to use with the json url ?

Thank you.

Comment: I looked through the documentation but seems like we can't do it from the method. Have you found any solution to it? If you did, post your solution so it might help others.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a workaround other than what you suggested, using the Distance Matrix API web service (remember that the API should be invoked from the server side, so you should wrap it in your own service).  It seems like language should be a parameter, so I created a public issue tracker which you can find here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11484&thanks=11484&ts=1487381207

Answer (score 1):

You can set a language when you load Maps JavaScript API in your page. It will be set globally for all further client side requests. Have a look at the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization#Language

However, indeed there is no way to specify a language different from the one set in a bootstrap in client side service requests. Hopefully, Rob's feature request will be implemented in the future.

Please star the feature request in the public issue tracker to add your vote and receive updates from Google.